# Absolute Newbie in Powershell has a question

Tags: powershell

I have an directory full of Log´s

My current code is

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path |Select-string -Pattern -AllMatches).matches.count
```

That will get me an 8 as output. But i want a list of all Logs with an hit and how many was in them.

Like This: `"File2020.09.02 17"`

How can i do that?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please take your time to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$files = Get-Childitem -Path 'C:\xyz' -File
$out = foreach ($file in $files){
    $content = Get-Content $file
    $matchCount = ($content | Select-String -Pattern 'xyz' -AllMatches).matches.count
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Filename = $file
        Matches = $matchCount
    }
}
$out
```

Comment: Ty its working <3 Do u know how to make it only put out files with hits?

Answer (score 0):

Since [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) returns `MatchInfo` objects with a `Filename` property, you can use `Group-Object` to group objects by `Filename`. [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7) inherently counts the occurrences of any passed properties.

```
Select-String -Path $path -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches |
    Group-Object -Property FileName | Foreach-Objecet {
        "{0} {1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Count
    }
```

`Group-Object`'s `Name` property contains the value of the grouped properties. Its `Count` property lists the number of occurrences where those grouped properties match among the piped in objects.

---

You can use a hash table to track the number of hits in your files.

```
$tracker = @{}
Select-String -Path $path -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {
    if ($tracker.Contains($_.Filename)) {
        $tracker[$_.Filename]++
    } else { 
        $tracker[$_.Filename] = 1
    }
}
$tracker.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
    "{0} {1}"-f $_.Key,$_.Value
}
```

Comment: didnt tested ur´s but ty very much for ur answer. <3